# Not able to install GIT on RHEL 7.1

Tags: installation, git, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to install git on rhel 7.1 using rpm.
and i am getting below errors.

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# rpm -ivh git-1.8.3.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm 
warning: git-1.8.3.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    perl(Git) is needed by git-1.8.3.1-4.el7.x86_64
    perl-Git = 1.8.3.1-4.el7 is needed by git-1.8.3.1-4.el7.x86_64
```

When i try to install perl-git.
I am getting below errors.

```
[root@localhost Desktop]# rpm -ivh perl-Git-1.8.3.1-4.el7.noarch.rpm 
warning: perl-Git-1.8.3.1-4.el7.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID fd431d51: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    git = 1.8.3.1-4.el7 is needed by perl-Git-1.8.3.1-4.el7.noarch
```

Can anybody help me in installing git?

Please note that **"yum install"** is not working in my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install both rpm's at the same time.

```
rpm -ivh git-*.rpm perl-Git-*.rpm
```